# Customizing The Google Directions for my Website and or my Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, dijkstra

I have currently stumbled upon the Google's direction maps where the user inputs a start address and an end address and after which it would generate a route from the start address to the end address. I found out that the generated route isn't efficient and doesn't consider the traffic of a certain street it highlights.

In my application I made a `Graph`. the graph consists `Vertices` and `Edges`
The Vertices are the intersection points and has their own respective Geo-locations.
The Edges are the ways from one vertex to another.

to get the shortest path of my Graph, I used Dijkstra's algorithm. An algorithm that would map out the most efficient route to take.

And so my problem is how could i customize the Highlighting of the Google map?

Comment: If this is about an Android app then it is **not** about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: Not sure about the integration of google maps but it is definitely worth to check out mapsforge - an offline map creation tool for android -- ah and I noticed you should already know graphhopper which is for android too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use google map android api to add shapes directly? Here is their official guide:

[google map android api add shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes)